# Convert Bytestring to "normal" String Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, argon2-ffi

I'm generating a argon2d hash and wanted to compare it with hashstring from my database.

For hashing I use this function:

```
    import argon2

    argon2Hasher = argon2.hash_password_raw(b"password", b"TESTTESTTESTTEST" ,time_cost=16, memory_cost=512, parallelism=1, hash_len=16,     type=argon2.Type.D) #argon2.low_level.Type.D)
    print(argon2Hasher)
```

And my output is:

```
b'\x0c\xd1\xe3\xf0\x0f\x03<\xa0\xa99\xee\x85I\xc8\xcb\xb0'
```

I tried to use `argon2Hasher.decode(encoding="ascii")` which resulted in:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)`
And I also tried the same command with `encoding="utf-8"` but this resulted in `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 1: invalid continuation byte`

How can I convert it into plaintext (normal String)?

I'm using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no way to tell **for sure** what encoding to use, there are some encoding that do not have *invalid values*, like e.g. `latin1`, trying that on your data yields this:

```
s = b'\x0c\xd1\xe3\xf0\x0f\x03<\xa0\xa99\xee\x85I\xc8\xcb\xb0'
repr(s.decode('latin1'))
# "'\\x0cÑãð\\x0f\\x03<\\xa0©9î\\x85IÈË°'"
```

The documentation of the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) package, provides you with a comprehensive list of what you can specify for encoding.

---

However, I think you are asking yourself the wrong question.
If the `bytes` you show are meant to represent a hash, then a conversion to `str` is not really desireable since, as you are experimenting yourself, this must also include an encoding for this to be "interpreted".
On the contrary, `bytes` is `bytes` and no extra encoding is needed.
This is the same reason that also [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) works primarily with `bytes`.

Comment: I wouldn't have any problems with sticking to bytes, but I'm using this for an API. I will recieve JSON objects and when I try to pass it with return jsonify(Hash= argon2_hash("password")) I get a" TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable". So I thought the person who will send me data will have to convert it to, so I will still have to adapt one side to the other

Comment: @CalBlau You could serialize `repr(bytes)` instead of `bytes`. That is always a string.